# Missing Enchanced Session setting in Hyper-V Manager

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows 2012 Server running with a Hyper-V role.
Wanted to enable Enhanced Session setting, but I cannot find it under Hyper-V Manager settings.
What gives?

Comment: I believe that's a new feature in Windows Server 2012 R2, not Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature was introduced in Windows Server 2012 R2: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282274.aspx.